# Is a rollback ever generated by any method other than clicking the rollback link?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

Recently, I edited a question to add some minor formatting. Later, I noticed that my edits had been rolled back and then the OP had then re-applied the exact same edits.

This seems like a very strange sequence of events, but it could make sense if the user doesn't know how to rollback and the original rollback was system-generated.

Is it possible for a rollback edit to be made without the user explicitly clicking the rollback link?

Comment: If the OP *improved* your edit I think that has the same effect as a "rollback"/re-apply.

Comment: @Paulie_D I feel like when I've "accepted and improved" a pending edit, I've seen that count as two separate edits. In this case, I'm past the 3K rep to go through the edit queue, so what mechanism would they have used to improve my edit?

Comment: One thing I noticed, recently, is that edits submitted quickly after another are not recorded in the edit history.  Like the post edit grace period is also active for rollbacks.  No real idea how long that's been that way, it is pretty hard to notice such edit attempts.  Only real way to tell is that the question still gets activated.

Comment: Grace period has always been active for edits, @hans - rollbacks are the exception (someone was complaining about that here recently, as they'd expected rolling back their edit to make their changes disappear from the revision history).

Comment: Shep is correct, @paulie - improve will generate two revisions, one for the suggestion and one for the improvement. "Reject and edit" discards the suggestion and generates a single revision - that's close, but not quite what's described here.

Comment: @shog9 - I did notice this on rollbacks.  Quacks like a bug.

Comment: I suppose a post owner who didn't want another user to be credited as editor, but who agreed with their edit, could *intentionally* rollback and then re-apply the same changes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I actually think that is the case this time; the OP and I have... history, but I figured the core part of the question was still valid ;-)

Comment: In case someone wants to know, here is the question where it happened: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50394209/4284627

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Things other than clicking "rollback" that will roll back a post to a previous revision:

- clicking "edit" from the revision history on a previous revision and submitting the edit.
- picking a previous revision from the revision drop-down on the full (not inline) editor.
- overriding a previous approval of a suggested edit (only possible for post owners and mods)

Comment: In the first two cases, the user would be presented with the ability to perform further edits in place, is that correct? If they do that, does it show up as two revisions in the history (rollback + edit) or just one? Since I've over 3K rep, my edit should not have been a suggested review, so that seems unlikely in *this* case.

Comment: Don't OPs always have the right to confirm edits to their posts?

Comment: It would show up as a single revision, @shep

Comment: Yes, @paulie - what's relevant here is that they can decline edits after they've already been approved, which means the approved revision has to be rolled back as part of that.

Comment: @Shog9 and just to be entirely sure: can an OP decline an edit that has taken effect but was never "approved" because it never went through the review queue? For example, those made by users of 3K+ rep.

Comment: Decline has no meaning in that context, @shep - they'd just roll back.

Comment: Are you sure about the first one?  I did that the other day and didn't see a rollback.  I forget if I only made tag edits, or if I changed anything else, too.

Comment: Yup, @Peter. I just made an edit and then made three rollbacks to this answer - the first two via the "rollback" link, the last via "edit" on the first revision. This is also how you can leave a revision comment when rolling back, but I didn't demonstrate that here.